# How can I pass the ID in the URL using SLIM Framework PHP?

Tags: php, slim, slim-3

I'm new to using SLIM framework, I'm working on a project/platform that allows users to post their listings and take bookings from potential clients. But I want them to be able to share a link to their listing.

I have provided the relevant code below, that is used to display all these listings on a single page. When clicking on one of the listings, the information is pushed into a modal. I'm looking to generate a link for each listing that can be shared via email or message and accessed easily.

At the minute I'm stuck with:

```
localhost/listings
```

My desired outcome is:

```
localhost/listings/+itemid/
```

Listings.html

```
function listingInfo($id,$location){

  // Detail View Specific

  $('.listing-info-container').addClass('active');
  $('.listing-info').html('').removeClass('active');
  showLoader($('.listing-info'));
  showLoader($('.listings-results'));

  setTimeout(function(){
    $.ajax({
      method: "GET",
      url: "/listing_information/"+$id
    })
    .done(function(result){
      $('.listing-info').html(result).addClass('active');
      hideLoader($('.listing-info'));
      hideLoader($('.listings-results'));
      // hide map if on mobile - link to external google maps site instead
      $('.listings-map').toggleClass('is-hidden', isMobile());
      // set co-ord vals in hidden textbox
      $('#listing-detail-directions-ll').val($location.toString().replace(/["'()]/g,'').replace(' ', ''));
    });
  }, 1000);
```

Listings.php

```
   //to display all listings on a single page
$app->get('/listings', function ($request, $response, $args) {
      $variables['title'] = 'Listings';
      $variables['categories'] = $this->db->select('listing_categories','*');

      return $this->view->render( $response, 'listings.html', $variables,);
    });
```

Answer (score 5):

Just mention the parameter in the route description like this:

```
$app->get('/listings/{id}', function ($request, $response, $args) {
...
```

Then you'll be able to access it within the route handler:

```
$route = $request->getAttribute('route');
$listingId = $route->getArgument('id');
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this out, I've tried get('/listings/{id}', ...) but I see what you're doing with defining the $listingID variable. When you say access it within the route handler, what do you mean by that? Apologises if its a clear answer, I'm new to Slim framework and this I haven't built the platform from scratch. I've just joined as a contributor

Comment: nitty picking: id should also be visible in `$args['id']` (slightly less indirection) https://www.slimframework.com/docs/v3/objects/router.html

Comment: Also works in Slim v4 inside of $app->group() callback.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
$app->get('/api/:version/users/:id', function ($version, $id) {
    // you can access $version and $id here
}
```

Comment: That seems to be for slim v2

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this on Slim v3 is:

```
$app->get('/listings/{id}', function ($request, $response, $id) {
    // do something with $id here
}
```

Since the parameter value gets captured by {id} and stored in the $id variable.